# Adding custom configuration in config.yml in Symfony 2.1

Tags: config, symfony-2.1

I want to do custom configuration parameters in `config.yml`
Example:
In `config.yml` file

```
security_enhancement:
     authentication:true
     authorization:true
```

In same format like `swiftmailer` configuration etc.I'm not getting idea how to define.
I'm getting error like:

```
1/2 ParseException: Unable to parse in "\/var\/www\/demo\/app\/config\/config.yml" at line 217 (near "authentication:true").
```

Am I missing something here? Is it necessary to add in depending injection extension file? .Actually I want to enable disable authentication,authorization execution during dev mode which is implemented in listener  which can be done using `config_dev.yml` . I don't want to add under Parameters. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've rightly theorised, you do indeed need to add in DI extension files, assuming your configuration relates to particular bundles (which it almost certain will).

Whilst parameters can simply be defined at will, configuration features hierarchical structure and validation.

Usually, configuration is used to in turn, define parameters, but it allows for the values to be parsed and validated prior to their instantiation, so that bundle writers can provide better guidance as to how their services can be used (with meaningful errors), and trust the values that are being passed into them.

A decent read on how to get started with config component can be found in the Symfony2 docs: [defining and processing configuration files with the config component](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/config/definition.html).

Comment: Okay,Ill didn't add configuration tree builder.Thanks for your answer.I'll try